# Convert from markdown to docx and keeping line break using Pandoc

Tags: pandoc, line-breaks, file-conversion

I want to convert a markdown file to docx and keeping the linebreak using pandoc.
the markdown look like this:

```
I'm a test about line break
in a docx document
```

And when using pandoc with the argument to preserve the wrapping I get:

```
I’m a test about line break in a docx document
```

So far I tried :

```
pandoc test.md --wrap=preserve -o test.docx
pandoc test.md --wrap=none -o test.docx
pandoc test.md -o test.docx
```

None worked.

I'm using pandoc 3.1.1 on OSX 12.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--wrap` option only affects the way the text is written in the output file, but does not affect the semantic meaning of a line break. For that we need a different extension: [`hard_line_breaks`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL#extension-hard_line_breaks):

> Extension: `hard_line_breaks`
>
> Causes all newlines within a paragraph to be interpreted as hard line breaks instead of spaces.

Use with `--from=markdown+hard_line_breaks`.